# What is the cxaguard library?

Tags: c++, abi

Code I inherited references -lcxaguard on the link line. However, this library apparently is no longer included with the Intel 15 C++ compiler and I'm getting `ld: cannot find -lcxaguard` errors. What is this library and what does 'cxa' mean?

Comment: http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/3647468/dir//com/intel-icc8-libs-8.1-0.i386.rpm.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this website](http://kiwi.atmos.colostate.edu/rr/tidbits/intel/macintel/doc_files/source/extfile/bldaps_for/files_32.htm) and [this one](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-c-compiler/topic/297080), it is a support library used in old versions of Intel C++ to support usage of the (now deprecated) switch `-cxxlib-gcc`. This switch allowed to use the runtime library (`libstdc++`) of the currently installed G++ version. This was needed because Intel C++ used to supply a runtime library made by Dinkumware. Since that is not the case anymore, the library was removed (and the switch deprecated) in up-to-date versions of Intel C++.